# Google reCAPTCHA working on Local but not on my server

Tags: recaptcha

I have a form which requires a google reCAPTCH to be ticked.  It is working perfectly on Local but does not work when I put it on the development server.  I have replaced the registered keys to the ones appointed to me by Google.

It keeps outputting the error message.

The method in my form is post.

I do not understand why it doesn't work.  Can someone please help me?

Here is my code:

```
        $secretKey = "#######";
        $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);

        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
            $throwErrorMessage = "You are a robot! ";
            $throwError = 1;
            $isvalid = False;
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of ReCAPTCHA are you using? The docs on Google website [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php) are pretty different than your code. In particular, you use the function `file_get_contents` while the documentation uses `recaptcha_check_answer` like in this example:

```
  <?php
   require_once('recaptchalib.php');
   $privatekey = "your_private_key";
   $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

   if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again."."(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
   } else {
     // Your code here to handle a successful verification
   }
  ?>
```

Can you post the error message?

Comment: I am using v2,  The sorry message is what I set it as:

"You are a robot"

This code that I written works for other forms, it's just this form that does not work and I can't work out why that is.

Comment: Try using `if ($responseKeys->success == false) { // error }`. Try also to print the value of `$responseKeys` to see if the variable is correctly created.